# What questions is French referring to?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-departed

In *The Departed (2006)*, Fitzy and Delahunt are playing "who's cop & whose not" in front of the bar.
Billy is sitting in the bar and there are a group of men sitting near him.
Frank comes in from the kitchen with his sleeves stained with blood.

> Frank: You can get out of here. I'm using a new crew tonight. New
> guys.
>
> Billy: I thought I was on for this.
>
> Frank: I changed my mind. Take the night off.

Frank goes back to the kitchen, the group of men follow him
back into the kitchen. Mr French turns to Billy & says:

> French: There's guys who answer the **questions** right...and  there's
> guys that don't.

What questions is French referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few scenes earlier, Costello is asking Billy questions while sussing out a rat...

```
                            COSTELLO
                    You got a girlfriend?
          
                                BILLY
                    No. No. What does that matter?
          
                              COSTELLO
                    Depends. I'm sure you know by now
                    there's an informer in my crew.
                    Cop. Staties or Boston Police
                    department, I'm not sure.
```

Then a bit later...

```
                    COSTELLO
            Point I'm making...you see...I got
            this rat...gnawing, cheese eating
            fucking rat...questions come
            up...questions...see, Bill, you're
            the new guy...and the girlfriend.
            Why don't you stay in the bar when
            I get the numbers. Your numbers.
            Everybody's numbers.
      
                           BILLY
                Is there something you want to ask
                me, Frank?
      
                          COSTELLO
                Start with, you agree there is a
                rat?
```

So, not so much specific questions, but Frank (Costello) is questioning who the rat it is in his organization. He was not satisfied that he knew, so he brought in a whole new crew for the job.